# Set dropdown menu parent background to transparent, keep children opaque

Tags: css

There is a navigation menu near the top of http://eaglesflight.sites.hubspot.com/conference for which I would like to have the parent items (TRAINING, COMPANY, RESOURCES) have transparent backgrounds, while maintaining the current opacity of the children on hover.

Essentially, I want to be able to see the background image behind the parent items of the navigation as opposed to the solid colour that is currently there.

I'm an amateur, tasked with doing some web development at work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only with CSS you can't ... because is impossible to change parent attributes on hover

Comment: brouxhaha was able to help me out. Thanks for taking the time to comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `background: #1d3d6f` from the `.nav-menu li` and add it to `.hs-menu-children-wrapper`

for the hover, remove `background: #fff` from `.nav-menu a:hover`

If you don't set a background-color, you'll see whatever is behind the element.

Comment: Worked perfectly! You're a legend. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 0):

> ...while maintaining the current opacity of the children on hover.

So seems like you already tryed to set a `opacity` to the element:

```
.hs-menu-wrapper.hs-menu-flow-horizontal>ul li.hs-item-has-children 
{
   position: relative;
   opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Now indeed, the child elements also have this hover. This is because the parent element is "stronger". You can just re-adjust the `opacity` on hover:

```
.hs-menu-item.hs-menu-depth-1.hs-item-has-children:hover 
{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CuQP/1/)

*Note The COMPANY is not semi-transparent, because it has no child element. You can change this if you want by including the element with no children to the semi-transparent opacity*

---

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: It was helpful, however that lowered the opacity of the parent link until hovered over. I apologize, I can see how what I was asking for was unclear. However, brouxhaha was able to solve my problem. Thanks for taking the time to comment!